# Подскажите, как в echo вставить php функцию

Tags: php, echo

```
function wrapper_end() {
echo '</div><div class="col-md-4"> тут должен php код </div></div></div>';}
```

сам php код:

```
<?php sidebar( 'widget-areas-1212' ); ?>
```

Comment: в чём именно проблема? почему бы просто не вставить сам код? `echo '<p><?php foo(\'bar\'); ?></p>';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function wrapper_end() {
  echo '</div><div class="col-md-4">';
  sidebar('widget-areas-1212');
  echo '</div></div></div>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$var = sidebar('text');
function name($var){
    echo "<div>" . $var . "</div>";
}
name($var);
```

Comment: Переменная `$var` не будет доступна в локальной области функции, без принудительного приглашения, через прототип или через `global` - что уже не рекомендуется в принципе.

Comment: @And, да, затупил жестко, не заметил. исправил.